# Testing if an Object is Nothing/null in VB.NET vs C#

Tags: c#-to-vb.net

I'm converting some C# code to VB.NET.  I have a simple dictionary-like data structure that contains name/value pairs.  The value element is of type Object.  My C# code looks like this

```
if(x.Value != null)
  // 1: Store x.Value in database
else
  // Sore DBNULL.Value in database
```

As expected, if x.Value happens to be a boolean of value false, code block 1 above executes.

However, the equivalent VB.NET code will fall through to the else block on a Boolean of False

```
If x.Value Is Not Nothing Then
  ' Store x.Value in database
Else
  ' We land here if x.Value is a Boolean with a value of False and incorrectly store DBNULL.Value in database
EndIF
```

VB apparently thinks a Boolean with a False value is equivalent to Nothing.
I'll keep my comments about VB to myself, but is there a non-convoluted way, i.e. without using reflection, to work around this problem?

Edit: my original VB code was actually

```
If x.Value <> Nothing
```

That worked as described.

```
If x.Value IsNot Nothing
```

works correctly.  Thanks Steve.

Comment: Have you tried with `if x.Value IsNot Nothing then`

Comment: FYI In VB, `Nothing` is not treated like null when compared with value types like boolean, like you'd expect in C#. Instead it is equal to that value type's default value, which is `false` for bool.

Answer (score 5):

You must use `IsNot` with no space between the `'Is'` and the `'Not'` in `vb`. So your code will look like this :

```
If x.Value IsNot Nothing Then  
   ...do Stuff...
Else 
   ...do else stuff...
End IF
```

Answer (score 4):

Use 
If x.Value Is DBNull.Value Then
...

Answer (score 0):

This is the proper match for VB.Net

`If Not IsNothing(x.Value) Then`

However checking for nulls is different.